# SSRS reports using prefiltering

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I want to run my report for each case associated with a contract for a customer. Right now I am able to run reports on the account level. I have used the filtering view as below:

```sql
dbo.FilteredAccount AS CRMAF_FilteredAccount 
on CRMAF_FilteredAccount.accountid = I.CustomerId 
WHERE A.PartyObjectTypeCode = 8 AND A.PartyIdName IS NOT NULL
```

I want to be able to run this same report against each case I have with the Account associated with a contract. I tried using FilteredIncident view but I'm not sure I am doing it right.

Query from comments:

```sql
SELECT I.CustomerIdName AS 'Customer Name',
       S.CreatedOn AS 'Task Start Date',
       S.Subject AS 'Task Performed',
       A.PartyIdName AS 'Resource',
       S.Description,
       cast((S.ActualDurationMinutes / 480) as varchar(5)) +' day(s)' + ', ' +
           cast((S.ActualDurationMinutes% 480) / 60 as varchar(2))+' hour(s)' 
           as 'Time Spent',
       S.ActualDurationMinutes AS 'Total Time',
       S.ActualDurationMinutes AS 'Total' 
FROM dbo.Incident I 
JOIN [dbo].[ServiceAppointment] S ON I.IncidentId = S.RegardingObjectId 
JOIN dbo.ActivityParty A ON S.ActivityId = A.ActivityId
```

Comment: Where's the rest of the query? The code snippet included does not look like an SSRS filtering expression.

Comment: SELECT  I.CustomerIdName AS 'Customer Name'
   ,S.CreatedOn AS 'Task Start Date'
      ,S.Subject AS 'Task Performed'
      ,A.PartyIdName AS 'Resource'
      ,S.Description 
      ,cast((S.ActualDurationMinutes / 480) as varchar(5))+' day(s)' 
      + ', '+cast((S.ActualDurationMinutes% 480) / 60 as varchar(2))+' hour(s)' as 'Time Spent'
      ,S.ActualDurationMinutes AS 'Total Time'
 ,S.ActualDurationMinutes AS 'Total'
  
  FROM dbo.Incident I JOIN
  [dbo].[ServiceAppointment] S
  ON I.IncidentId = S.RegardingObjectId
  JOIN dbo.ActivityParty A
  ON S.ActivityId = A.ActivityId

Comment: This is the query. This fetches all tha details from an Account level. I want to run the report from a case level for the account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add a CaseID in your select list and a parameter to compare it to in the report. So you would add something like this to your WHERE clause:

```
WHERE I.CaseID = @SelectedCase
```

Comment: By adding the WHERE clause, will I be able to run the report for any case for any account?

Comment: Thank you Steven! It worked. I don't know how I didn't think of adding the WHERE clause! Thank you again!